# R httr:add_headers() not working

Tags: r, header, addition, httr

I need to pass a custom header for a `GET` request using `httr` package in `R`, I checked the vignettes but can't get it right and looking for some help.

```
CusAuth <- c(database="database",user="login id",password="password")

GET(url,add_headers(.headers = CusAuth))
```

Comment: Are you getting some error? Did you try `CusAuth` as a named list?

Answer (score 1):

I had to include the vector member within quotes so it is sent as a single value to the header and this is working now.

```
CusAuth <- c('database="database",user="login id",password="password"')
```